# Прибавить к атрибуту модели значение из формы. Django

Tags: python, django

Только начал изучать Django. Есть форма. Хочу из одного из ее полей получить целое значение и прибавить это значение к одному из атрибутов имеющейся модели(`Product`). Вот модели:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'Product'

    idModel = models.ForeignKey(SkiModel)
    growth_from = models.IntegerField()
    growth_to = models.IntegerField()
    weight_from = models.IntegerField()
    weight_to = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    quantity_in_stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Delivery(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'Delivery'

    Product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    Amount = models.IntegerField()
    Receipt_date = models.DateField()
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Вот форма:

```
class DeliveryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Delivery
        fields = 'Product', 'Amount', 'Receipt_date'
```

Вот функция в `views.py`:

```
def add_delivery(request, user_id):
    if request.POST:
        form = DeliveryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Delivery = form.save(commit=False)
            Delivery.User = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            form.save()
            Product.objects.get(id=int(form['Product'].value())).quantity_in_stock += int(form['Amount'].value())
    return redirect('/Delivery/')
```

Не прибавляется. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А где `save()` для изменённой записи БД?

Comment: Cпасибо. pr = Product.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('Product')))
            pr.quantity_in_stock += int(request.POST.get('Amount'))
            pr.save()

Answer (score 1):

Изменённые записи необходимо записывать:

```
pr = Product.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('Product')))
pr.quantity_in_stock += int(request.POST.get('Amount'))
pr.save()
```